# How can I evaluate availability of security updates for CyanogenMod / Cyanogen OS

Tags: cyanogenmod, ota-update

Suppose I'm looking at a Cyanogen OS phone.  It seems to be very difficult to find a history of available build versions (and compare the dates e.g. to the first build of that version available for *any* phone, or when the security issues it fixes were released).

How can I check the quality of this support for a specific phone, like the WileyFox Swift?

Do I need to forget about complaints for community-maintained CyanogenMod... just look at commercial Cyanogen OS as a monolith, and ask how well they're doing in general?  Is there a written evaluation of this anywhere?

[I'd like to think of Cyanogen OS as more credible than vendors who go through carriers.  And only promised monthly security updates after the most glaring remote security hole a few months back.  Or who just completely fail on updates after claiming they wouldn't, because of a change in ownership.  But I can't even find marketing claims about the superiority of Cyanogen OS here, so this seems fairly wishful thinking on my part].

Comment: This questions seems very unclear, have you investigated yourself? Cyanogenmod.org

Comment: Yes. At least enough to see that Cyanogen explicitly don't keep old releases available for download.  So you can't just look at timestamps on available downloads.  All I'm asking is "does Cyanogen * have reliable security updates".  Seems pretty clear it's not true in the general case.  However I gave a specific example of a Cyanogen OS <del>target (EDIT)</del> phone which I could buy - I guess the real question I'm asking is whether for my money I can expect security issues to be resolved within 30 days

Comment: or so, i.e. that would be comparable with the "monthly updates" standard some of the vendors have recently claimed they would provide.

Comment: Well unless you're gonna pay therm whatever the cost is to keep the hundred of nighties and data that is generated every single day, I don't expect how they can financially do this (keep old nighties) Also you seem to confuse Cyanogen OS and Cyangenmod. Latest avoidable nighty for officially supported Cyangenmod are from February 19.

Comment: I'm not confused, it's likely I'm being unclear though :). I don't expect them to keep archives of the snapshot releases for X devices and Y months. I'm just saying because they're not there, there's no clear way to look at the version history on the Cyanogen websites. I.e. to answer your question, I _have_ looked at the link you gave, and it doesn't seem to give the information I'm interested in.  The history of "snapshot" releases over time would be much more useful than the date of the latest nightly in answering the question of *reliable* security updates, right?

Comment: I may be making unjustified assumptions in that I assume if CyanogenMod is doing OK. for a Cyanogen OS device, that would be an excellent sign for the Cyanogen OS (provided the vendor is still in business).

Comment: Cyanogen OS was similar to CyanogenMod, in that I was able to find a page of factory images for the WileyFox Swift, but it only showed the most recent version.